# responsive video makes white spaces in mobile screen

Tags: html, css

I have a page that have responsive video in it, it works great in laptop or any wide screen, but i face a problem of white space above nad below the video in vertical screen like mobiles, i  used following ccs code:

```css
.background-video {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -10;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(50%, 0);
  transform: translate(50%, 0);
  background: url(../video/video.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.section-video {
 position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 0;

}
.section-video .bgvid {
 -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

here is live preview:

http://shiftmkt.sa/tec/

Comment: Remove width:100% from .section-video .bgvid then check

Comment: thanks, it fill the white spaces, but, now not full video shown in mobile it cut from the edges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this.**
Let me know if you need any changes.

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.section-video .bgvid {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-video">
                <video autoplay="" poster="video/video.jpg" class="bgvid" loop="">
                    <source src="http://shiftmkt.sa/tec/video/video.webm" type="video/webm">
                    <source src="http://shiftmkt.sa/tec/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="http://shiftmkt.sa/tec/video/video.ogv" type="video/ogv">
                </video>
            </div>
```